# Java calling method on all objects of specific type

Tags: java

Okay, the title is a little bit cryptic, an example will show better what I mean, suppose the following structure:

```
interface I { 
    methodCall();
}

class A implements I {
}

class B implements I {
}

class C implements I {
}

class Main {
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;

    //other interesting stuff

    void doSomeMainMethod() {
        a.methodCall();
        b.methodCall();
        c.methodCall();
    }
}
```

This code has been heavily simplified, the classes `A`, `B` and `C` implement `methodCall()` obviously, but there is no need to explicitely show that in the code.

What I want to ask is the following:
Is there a way to tell Java to *generate* my `doSomeMainMethod` method? I want to tell Java to call `methodCall()` on all objects of type `I` in class `Main`.

Preferably without the use of reflection, because with reflection I think it is possible or if reflection is needed, is there a way to wrap it up such that it at least looks non-hackish? Ofcourse it needs to be safe (as safe as possible) aswell.

Comment: Do you use plain java or with any dependency injection framework?

Comment: @JakubK Just plain old java. Using Java 7 currently, but answer with Java 8 are also appreciated.

Comment: I agree, injection is the only way to get external implementation.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, even with DI. You can't find out what are the subclasses (or class implementing the interface), without manually scanning the classpath, and loading all the classes. With Di also, you can't be sure everytime an instance of a different implementing class is injected, to the reference of interface type.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
private A a;
private B b;
private C c;
private I[] instances = new I[]{a, b, c};

//other interesting stuff

void doSomeMainMethod() {
    for(I instance : instances) {
        instance.methodCall();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the method to be generated then you can use ASM generation or (probably simpler option) implement your own AnnotationProcessor. With the second option you should annotate your classes and then scan for this annotation in compile time and generate decired method.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface I {
  void methodCall();
  List<I> INSTANCES = new ArrayList<I>();
}
```

Now, in every constructor of classes that implements interface I, do this:

```
I.INSTANCES.add(this);
```

In main:

```
for (I i : I.INSTANCES) {
  // do something with every instance of I
}
```

**EDIT:**
This will add all instances of I. To limit it to the objects created in Main, let´s add a parameter, createdBy. It is not quite elegant, but it is just Java, no Reflection ...

```
public A(Class createdBy) {
  if (createdBy.equals(Main.class) {
    I.INSTANCES.add(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds rather interesting, though waiting to see if there's any advice to not use it.

Comment: this is wrong, it will call the method on all the instances of I (even those outside of Main), since INSTANCES is a static field. The question was how to call the method on all objects of type I in class Main. Or maybe the question was ambiguous?

Comment: @MarcinKrupa yes, you´re right. Well, maybe a parameter in constructor will tell who created the instance may help. public A(Class createdBy) { if (createdBy.equals(Main.class) { I.INSTANCES.add(this); } }